# Selenium Python : extract field from json data in <a> tag

Tags: python, json, selenium, xpath

On a particular webpage, I have the following  tag :

```
<a id="AAA" class="BBB" data-json="{"link":"thelink","field1":1,"field2":5}">
Load more
</a>
```

I am using Selenium / Python. I want to click 5 times on this  tag, where 5 is the value from "field2" in "data-json".

The XPATH is ".//*[@id='AAA']" (thanks to FireXPath) so I want to use 5 times the following command:

```
browser.findElement(By.XATH(".//*[@id='AAA']")).click();
```

Question is : how to extract this "5" from < a tag > / data-json / field2 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentionned by peers, it would be far better with **id**.

You can use `get_attribute` and json convertion:

```
>>> import json
>>> data = browser.find_element_by_id("AAA").get_attribute("data-json")
>>> json.loads(data)["field2"]
>>> 5
```

Comment: It would be more better if try using `browser.findElement(By.ID("AAA")).get_attribute("data-json")`..:)

Answer (score 1):

To get the value of an attribute you can use the function `get_attribute` [link](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.get_attribute), in this particular case we have to parse the data-json to a dict and get the number. My suggest is:

```
import json    
json_dict = json.loads(browser.findElement(By.ID('AAA')).get_attribute('data-json'))
number_times = json_dict["field2"]
```